# Why Can't I declare two equal forms with the same attributes?

Tags: php, html, forms

The only difference is that one form contains the input text and the other one contains the input submit. The reason I am doing this is because I have a large amount of code and I wrote the HTML first placing some input text at the top and the submit button at the end. Here is my code

This is for a project that contains a lot of HTML forms, what is the best practice when having many forms?

```
<!-- first form -->
  <form  method="post" action="test.php">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Amount" name="amount">
  </form>


  <form method="post" action="test.php">
    <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" >
  </form>

<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['amount'])){
      echo $_POST['amount'];
    }else{
      echo 'empty';
    }
  }
  ?>
```

It should print the values in  $_POST['amount'] if its not empty but instead it prints 'empty' all the time. thanks!

Comment: Your submit button will only submit form data for the form that it belongs to. That form only has one element, and that is the submit button. The form with the amount input needs its own submit button.

Comment: Thank you! i figured that it works by placing the form at the top of the page

Answer (score 0):

Server Side PHP should look like below:

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" placeholder="Amount" value="">
    </div>

    <div>
        <div><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

@pteran, that's not it. The positions of the two form do not matter. You are two form, the first one does not have a submit button and the second one have nothing to submit. And least, you can write something in the first form and press  on the keyboard and you will see the amount.

You need to group the text field and the button in the same form.

```
<!-- first form -->
  <form  method="post" action="test.php">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Amount" name="amount">
    <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" >
  </form>

<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['amount'])){
      echo $_POST['amount'];
    }else{
      echo 'empty';
    }
  }
  ?>
```